# Is it possible to change or rename sharepoint 2013 online site?

Tags: sharepoint-online

If I created a site called http://www.example.com/site1, how can I rename or change the site name to http://www.example.com/site2? If yes, how do I do it? And would it affect subsites and the content within site1?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem. Instead of attempting to rename my site, I saved the site as template. I was then able to create new sub site with the web address(URL) I wanted to use. The following post was very helpful.

[How to Save Site as Template in SharePoint 2013](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/11/23/how-to-save-site-as-template-in-sharepoint-2013/)

In addition, I discovered that SharePoint online uses a very limited subset of PowerShell; therefore this limited number of options I discovered searching the web.